# Cordova Plugin With Electron Support

Tags: electron, cordova-plugins

I'm trying to expand a custom cordova plugin to support electron platform (not browser!) using nodeJS.

However as Electron platform support in Cordova is new, I cannot find any examples out there.

Can anyone point me towards an example? Just need a start to help me get my head around it.

Many thanks!